# How to test limitation of memory when parsing XML files

Tags: java, xml, parsing, memory, out-of-memory

I'm trying to run to the point of `OutOfMemoryException`. My method creates a file, parse if there's no error then delete the file immediately, clear garbage collection and generate a bigger file and repeat. However big files consume too much time and CPU. Is there any better way to do this? Thanks.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 6000000; i <= 10000000; i+=100000) {
        WriteXml(i);
        try {
            File fXmlFile = new File("limit.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
                    } catch (SAXException | IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            fXmlFile.delete();
            };
        } catch (Exception  e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        System.gc();
    }
}
```

Comment: So what are you asking exactly?
How to parse XML in a more memory-efficient manner? Use SAX or StAX parsers, not DOM.
Or how to check memory consumption? Use a profiler for this.

Comment: ... Why do you want to cause a `OutOfMemoryException`?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how big the XML file would be to cause out of memory exception

Comment: I'm doing an assignment which evaluates parsers and one requirement is finding how big the XML that would cause out of memory.

Comment: So, if your xml file is too big when you call `dBuilder.parse`, it should throw an `OutOfMemoryException`?

Comment: My understanding is a little lacking here; however, isn't that depending on the JVM that is running on the machine? With my understanding, the computer runs a program that is able to run Java (JVM, right?). So the answer would be however much memory the JVM is allowed to use.

Comment: Yeah exactly, it depends on the computer. However, the requirement still requires so... I run out of memory when using JMH to test 6 million elements file but I'm able to even generate and parse at the same time in Eclipse that big file.

Comment: maybe you should double the size on each try. if you then get a out of memory error then i would do the same approach on the remaining space. then i would repeat this approach until the remaining space is so low that i wouldn't care of the diff and take the latest result. (recursion is your friend)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect (from my observations) that if you try to write a very flat tree (10m elements as children of the root, say), then you hit O(n^2) performance in adding new siblings at the end of a very long list, and you run out of time (or patience) before you run out of memory.

I wrote a little test using Saxon APIs so I could try this with different tree models (perhaps you could use the same idea):

```
    public void testDomSizeLimits() {
        try {
            for (int i=1; i<Integer.MAX_VALUE; i*=2) {
                System.err.println("Trying size " + i);
                Configuration config = new Configuration();
// Change the next line depending on the chosen tree model
                TinyBuilder writer = new TinyBuilder(config.makePipelineConfiguration());
                Location loc = ExplicitLocation.UNKNOWN_LOCATION;
                writer.open();
                writer.startDocument(0);
                writer.startElement(new NoNamespaceName("doc"), Untyped.getInstance(), loc, 0);
                for (int j=0; j<i; j++) {
                    writer.startElement(new NoNamespaceName("elem"), Untyped.getInstance(), loc, 0);
                    writer.characters("The quick brown fox", loc, 0);
                    writer.endElement();
                }
                writer.endDocument();
                writer.close();
            }
        } catch (XPathException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Both DOM and JDOM2 became unbearably slow after about 16M records. Saxon's TinyTree, however, carries on until it runs out of memory:

```
Trying size 1
Trying size 2
Trying size 4
Trying size 8
Trying size 16
Trying size 32
Trying size 64
Trying size 128
Trying size 256
Trying size 512
Trying size 1024
Trying size 2048
Trying size 4096
Trying size 8192
Trying size 16384
Trying size 32768
Trying size 65536
Trying size 131072
Trying size 262144
Trying size 524288
Trying size 1048576
Trying size 2097152
Trying size 4194304
Trying size 8388608
Trying size 16777216
Trying size 33554432
Trying size 67108864

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3284)
    at net.sf.saxon.tree.tiny.TinyTree.ensureNodeCapacity(TinyTree.java:233)
    at net.sf.saxon.tree.tiny.TinyTree.addNode(TinyTree.java:345)
    at net.sf.saxon.tree.tiny.TinyBuilder.makeTextNode(TinyBuilder.java:405)
    at net.sf.saxon.tree.tiny.TinyBuilder.characters(TinyBuilder.java:381)
    at jaxptest.DOMTest.testDomSizeLimits(DOMTest.java:1424)
```

This was run with defaulted heap size under IntelliJ.

A more reasonable test would probably increase the tree depth as the number of nodes increases. Don't have time to try that today.

Comment: Thanks, Michael, as I downloaded Saxon API and used your code, my machine could parse up to 33 million elements. But when I use JMH, it runs out of memory with 6 million elements. Do you know why is that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough experience with JMH to test. Obviously you need to ensure that both environments have the same amount of memory allocated for the results to be comparable. But it's possible that JMH is uses additional resources for instrumentation.

Answer (score 1):

Raw file size in bytes is not the only factor that might lead to `OutOfMemoryException`; amount and nature of the markup might also contribute.  So, you might want your tests to include some combination of the following possibilities:

- **Low markup test:**  Create an XML file with a single root element and vary the amount of text, $t, within that element: `<r>$t</r>` for $t
  with 100M, 1G, 10G, 100G, etc lengths.
- **High markup breadth test:**  Create an XML file where some markup, $b, appears numerous times within the root element: `<r>$b</r>` for $b
  repeated an increasing number of times.
- **High markup depth test:**  Create an XML file where some markup, $d, appears recursively numerous times from root element: $d = `<r>$d</r>` for $d
  recursed an increasing number of times.